# How to do simple javascript looping in protractor

Tags: protractor

```
for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
                console.log(i);  
                });

    }
```

I am trying to run this using protractor, but i get hundred times 100 printed in console. I have some functionality which am trying to implement using looping.**How can i do looping in protractor**?

Comment: At least from your code the problem is not protractor, but your lack of knowledge for JS variable scoping and async coding. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1169798 for a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the functions you're passing to `then` all close over the *variable* `i`, not the *value* that variable has when you create the functions. So later, when the functions are called, they all see the value of `i` as it is *then*, after the loop is complete (100).

If you want to capture the value of `i` as it is when you create the function, you can use ES5's `Function#bind`:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(index, browserLog) {
        console.log(index);  
    }.bind(null, i));
}
```

`bind` returns a new function that, when called, will call the original function with a given `this` value (in this case I'm using `null`) and any arguments you follow that with, followed by arguments given to the function `bind` returned.

Another approach is a builder function:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(buildHandler(i));
}
function buildHandler(index) {
    return function(browserLog) {
        console.log(index);
    };
}
```

That has the advantage of allowing the caller to control `this`.

Comment: @Rahul: No "bad," a lot of people don't get this at first. :-) Glad that helped.